# Published app didn't show while search in google play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We published a android application on google play store, the google play console said it's published. But we search our application in google play store it didn't show the application. When search the application with package name of our application it shows only in some devices. We didn't restrict any devices while publish the application. 
First we publish a application that was removed by google play for violating 'Google Play Developer Program Policies', we lost the old keystore file, so we change the package name and publish the application and it published. But it didn't show when we search by it's app name. We name the application as the first one removed from play store. 
we think the name of the application is same as the old one that was removed is the problem for that not showed in search list. We need solution for this.

Comment: It takes some time for google store to index your application. Just wait a bit. It can take some time

Comment: This question doesn't seem programming related

Comment: It'll take time to index your app. Try searching your app by your app id. If it's live in play store, it'll be shown.